# Can I torify all connections going through my hotspot?

Tags: proxy, web-proxy, pre-tor-proxy, torify

I am connected to the Internet through `eth0` and I run hotspot with wlan0:

```
 create_ap wlan0 wlan0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
```

Is it possible to torify the connections made by the users connected to the hotspot?

---

PS: 
* I am looking to do the same job as `torify` or `proxychains` but for all connections made on 
* I want users to use common applications and don't need to use ad hoc proxified applications. E.g they would use `firefox` and not `tor-browser`.
`wlan0`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. The tunneling process( aka "torification") uses exactly the same scripts and tools as the wired one: you can choose any of well-known ones like PORTAL or OnionPi - or create your own. But there're some tricks - I've figured them so far when I'm developing my solution:

- WiFi interface can flap some times, i.e. when your usb dongle is too hot. To mitigate so - use ifup/ifdown scripts to add **and** remove corresponding rules and/or restarting a sevices like DHCPD
- Hostapd and wifi drivers in Linux are too "quiet" about errors, especially when the dongle just hangs. Some dongles - like ath9k-based ones - need all the led's disabled *before* starting hostapd - it prevent them from hanging dead